# Inequality $\frac{{b{e^{bx}} - a{e^{ax}}}}{{b - a}}<e^{(a+b)x}$

Tags: inequality

How to prove $$\displaystyle \frac{{b{e^{bx}} - a{e^{ax}}}}{{b - a}}<e^{(a+b)x}$$ for $0<a<b$ and $x\ne 0$ ?

Comment: So in other words you want to prove that $be^{bx}\lt (b-a)e^{(a+b)x}+ae^{ax}$.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, we can rearrange the original inequalities as follows:
$$
\displaystyle {{b{e^{bx}} }}<(b-a)e^{(a+b)x}+a{e^{ax}}
$$
Here you can use Jensen but if you do not want to use notion of convexity, you can use [the weighted arithmetic geometric inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), which is:
$$
w_1x_1+w_2x_2\geq (w_1+w_2)(x_1^{w_1}x_2^{w_2})^{\frac{1}{w_1+w_2}}
$$
which gives you:
$$
\displaystyle (b-a)e^{(a+b)x}+a{e^{ax}}\geq  (b-a+a)(e^{a.ax+(b-a)(b+a)x})^{\frac{1}{b}}
$$

---

This does NOT mean that the proof is independent of Jensen inequality. It is only so, if you do not  use Jensen inequality to prove weighted AG inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use Jensen inequality for $e^x$ with suitable weights...

Answer (score 2):

The proof independent of Jensen's: multiply both sides by the denominators and group the terms to end up with
$$\frac{be^{bx}}{e^{bx}-1}\ge \frac{ae^{ax}}{e^{ax}-1}.$$
Now fix $x$ and consider the function $f(t)=\frac{te^{tx}}{e^{tx}-1}=t+\frac{t}{e^{tx}-1}.$ Note, $f'(t)=\frac{e^{tx}(e^{tx}-1-tx)}{(e^{tx}-1)^2}\ge 0,$ since $e^y\ge 1+y$ and thus $f(b)\ge f(a)$ for $b\ge a>0.$

Comment: first of all $e^y\ge 1+y$ for ALL $y.$ Second of all the derivative I found is correct modulo that i did not close the bracket for the power which of course does not affect the solution.

Comment: And the final note: this method should work as long as the problem statement is correct, since all over conclusions work in two directions (if and only if).

Comment: sorry!    you are right.